# Evaluating limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}2x(a+x(e^{-a/x}-1))$

Tags: limits

I'm stumped by the following limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}2x(a+x(e^{-a/x}-1))$

Mathematica gives the answer as $a^2$ but I'd like to know the evaluation steps.  I've staring at it for a while, but can't figure it out.  Seems like you can't use L'Hopital's rule on this one.  I've tried substitution $y=1/x$ but that didn't help.  I am probably not seeing something simple.  Any hints?

Comment: hint: expand $e^{-a/x}$ to second order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**:

$$
   \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} 2x \left(a + x \left(\mathrm{e}^{-a/x}-1\right)\right) = 2 a^2  \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}  \frac{ \exp\left(-\frac{a}{x}\right) - 1 + \frac{a}{x} }{\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^2} = 2 a^2 \lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}  \frac{ \exp\left(-y\right) - 1 + y }{y^2} 
$$
Now use l'Hospital's rule twice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\, $ For $\rm\, z = \displaystyle-\frac{a}x\: $ it's $\displaystyle\rm\:2a^2 \lim_{z\to 0^{-}}\frac{f(z)-(f(0)+f'(0)\,z)}{z^2}\, =\, a^2\, f''(0),\ \  f = e^z,\, $ by  Taylor / L'Hospital.